# Apache Ignite - SQL query on a simple cache

Tags: sql, ignite

I need to perform SQL Queries on my simple key-value cache where key and value are string types. 
I understand from documnetation that I should add queryEntities property for that, so I added this to my cache configurations:

```
                <property name="queryEntities">
                    <list>
                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                                    <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                    <property name="valueType" value="java.lang.String"/>

                            </bean>
                    </list>
            </property>
```

based on the example here : https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#scan-queries.

However,I still can't perform SQL on my cache with "Table not found" error.

I am new to Ignite so I wonder if I missing something here another step.
my cache is a simple key-value So I don't need those fields shown in the Person example.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your code the following should work:

```
SELECT _KEY, _VAL FROM "cacheName".STRING;
```